# Kendo UI DateTimePicker - Show 30 minute intervals from 00:30 till 24:00

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I'm using the [Kendo UI DateTimePicker](//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datetimepicker/index) to accept user input for a 30 minute period of a day. I am specifying a 30 minute interval explicitly (30 is default anyway) and I am using the format and timeFormat options to specify the 24 hour time format as you can see below.

When selecting the time drop down list I would like the values to start at 00:30 and go to **24:00** rather than the usual behaviour of starting at 00:00 and going to 23:30. Although using 24:00 to indicate midnight / the end of the day isn't that common in user interfaces, the [Wikipedia article on the 24 hour clock](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) indicates our requirement is not unheard of.

I've had a pretty good look through the [DateTimePicker API documentation](//docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/datetimepicker#configuration) but I can't find any 
*"officially supported"* way to do this. Any ideas to help me as I start to dive into the JavaScript guts of the widget? I also wonder if I could hack it by using a different culture?

To see a working example I've created a sample [JSFiddle](//jsfiddle.net/mgholls/a7K6g/)

```
$("#periodInput").kendoDateTimePicker({
    format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
    timeFormat: "HH:mm",
    interval: 30
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Kendo UI Forums posting ["TimePicker does not conform to IS0 8601 3.5.2 on Time of Day midnight representations"](http://www.telerik.com/forums/timepicker-does-not-conform-to-is0-8601-3-5-2-on-time-of-day-midnight-representations) describes the underlying problem. My attempted summary is:

- The Kendo UI Date/TimePicker controls work with the underlying [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- The [ECMAScript 5. standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) states that the Date Time string format is based on the ISO 8601 
  Extended Format which includes the midnight representation of **24:00**
- Some browsers support parsing a string format with **24:00** but not all at the moment (Chrome 35.0, Safari 7.0)
- As far as I know none of the browsers support a [DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) specifier that will output 24:00 for midnight.

It seems to me that to solve this problem using the DateTimePicker, I would be hacking away at the Kendo code at a pretty low level. While that sounds like fun, it's probably not appropriate value for my project at the moment.

After reviewing the requirements I have replaced the DateTimePicker widget with a DatePicker and a separate DropDownList. Using a separate DropDownList allows me to bind to a list of time periods that are not JavaScript Date objects and I can display a text representation of 24:00 to indicate the final half hour of the day.